# Update image src using AJAX and PHP function

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I want to change my image on click function using AJAX in WordPress.
Here is my code:

JS:

```
jQuery(".swatchinput label").click(function(){
     var mycolor = jQuery(this).attr("data-option");
     var postid = jQuery(".single-product .product.type-product").attr("data-id");

        jQuery.ajax({
            cache: false,
            timeout: 8000,
            url: php_array.admin_ajax,
            type: "POST",
            data: ({ action:'theme_post_vimage', colorimg: mycolor, postvalue: postid}),

                  beforeSend: function() {                    
            },

            success: function(response){

                var myimageresponse = jQuery( response );
                jQuery( '.product-image a img' ).attr('src', myimageresponse);                                                      

            },

            error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                console.log( 'The following error occured: ' + textStatus, errorThrown );   
            },

            complete: function( jqXHR, textStatus ){
            }


            });
    });
```

And this is my Function in PHP/WordPress:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_theme_post_vimage','theme_post_vimage_init');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_theme_post_vimage', 'theme_post_vimage_init' );
function theme_post_vimage_init() { ?>
<?php
global $post, $product, $woocommerce;    

 $postiID = $_POST['postvalue'];
 $colorname = $_POST['colorimg'];


$product = new WC_Product_Variable( $postiID );
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
    if($variation['attributes']['attribute_pa_color'] == $colorname) :
    $myimageurl = $variation['image']['url'];
    echo $myimageurl;
    endif;
}
?>

<?php }
```

When I click on my color, this error shows in my browser console:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://samsonite.stuntmen.ae/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/PROD_COL_73353_1726_WHEEL-HANDLE-FULL.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery( response );` is wrong... why not use `response` directly?

```
        success: function(response){

            jQuery( '.product-image a img' ).attr('src', response);                                                      

        },
```

furthermore, I suggest you change your implementation to something like this.

**PHP**

```
function theme_post_vimage_init() { 

    $postiID = $_POST['postvalue'];
    $colorname = $_POST['colorimg'];


    $product = wc_get_product( $postiID );
    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    $return = array(
        'status' => 'failed',
    );
    foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
        if($variation['attributes']['attribute_pa_color'] == $colorname) :
            $return = array(
                'status' => 'success',
                'url' => $variation['image']['url'],
            );
        endif;
    }
    wp_send_json($return);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(".swatchinput label").click(function(){
     var mycolor = jQuery(this).attr("data-option");
     var postid = jQuery(".single-product .product.type-product").attr("data-id");

    jQuery.ajax({
        cache: false,
        timeout: 8000,
        url: php_array.admin_ajax,
        type: "POST",
        data: ({ action:'theme_post_vimage', colorimg: mycolor, postvalue: postid}),

              beforeSend: function() {                    
        },

        success: function(response){
            if ( response.status === 'success' ) {
               jQuery( '.product-image a img' ).attr('src', response.url);   
            }
            // you can also do something for response.status === 'failed'                    

        },

        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            console.log( 'The following error occured: ' + textStatus, errorThrown );   
        },

        complete: function( jqXHR, textStatus ){
        }


        });
});
```

look for `success` I made changes.

Answer (score 2):

Replace line  `data: ({ action:'theme_post_vimage', colorimg: mycolor, postvalue: postid}),` with

```
data: { action:'theme_post_vimage', colorimg: mycolor, postvalue: postid},
```

And in youir ajax output you are putting unnecessary white spaces by using '?>

And more importantly what is `jQuery( response )` in your success function ? use `response` only.